# Google Maps Directions API Optimize waypoints with exceeding 23 waypoints

Tags: python, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

There are several posts already about getting directions to Google Maps API if your waypoints exceed 23, but the answers about it do not account for if optimize_waypoints is True. The difference is, adding one stop to the list of addresses could throw off the whole route optimization equation. Does anyone have any suggested work-arounds for it?

I was thinking maybe running it once, dropping off the smallest mileage different stops (say if I send 26, drop off the 3 smallest), then running it again, then somehow reconcile the two routes? Is there a more efficient or cleaner way? Any thoughts? Thanks!

I am using Python, but this is not a question to specific Python. More of a general programming and Google Maps directions question. But answers referencing Python would be most appreciated!

Comment: Read your question twice. Have no idea what is the issue you describe (*throw off the whole route optimization equation* ??) and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: In short: I need to get Google Maps Directions to work with more than 23 a, which is their API limit. But the difference between my case and other questions that have been asked about this is that I need Google Maps to also optimize the waypoints. So I can't just append more waypoints on to it like is done in other answers, because I don't know whether to put that waypoint in the sequence.

Comment: The limit is 23 for all customers via API or web service. See the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#waypoint-limits). So if it is not possible, then it is not possible. Solutions: 1) Find an existing or open a new feature request in the hope that Google will change it or 2) Find another directions provider that allows for more waypoints and route optimization or 3) Find a way to optimize the waypoints by yourself prior to requesting directions and use one of the workarounds you saw

Answer (score 1):

We have an entry for this feature request for including more than 23 waypoints in Directions API requests in the Google Issue Tracker so that we can provide information on it to all Google Maps APIs users, as the technical aspects of this issue are of interest to a number of our customers,

Issues in the Issue Tracker are directly curated by Directions API specialists, who will provide updates in the Issue Tracker whenever there's news from the engineering team.

We would like to warmly invite you to view the issue in the Issue Tracker, and to star it to register your interest. This will subscribe you to receive technical updates on the issue. Starring the issue also provides us with valuable feedback on the importance of the issue to our customers, and increases the issue's priority with the product engineering team.

You can view and star the issue here:
- https://issuetracker.google.com/35824756

This Issue Tracker entry is the authoritative source for public information regarding this issue, and all publicly-relevant updates will be posted there.